# How To Change Panel/view in the Windows Client Area in MFC

Tags: mfc

I want to design a student registration and exam recording app using C++ MFC with a kind of child window containing buttons edits and other common controls which is displayed on the app client area, and can be removed and replaced with another one by clicking a button. Thats the problem i face now( The GUI ). I came from JAVA background where this can be done by creating a JPanel as a container for the buttons, combo boxes and text fields controls. the panel is displayed on the client area and can be removed and replaced with another panel containing a new set of controls. I tried learning CView but it keeps talking about documents and views that displays untitled document as in word processing. Any pointer will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have a look here for a starting point: http://www.functionx.com/visualc/dialogboxes/mfcpspp.htm

Comment: Looks like what i'm looking for. Thanks, I'll go through it.

Comment: The site is loaded with information, it is more than what i was looking for. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

After having searched and read a lot about my problem, i decided to go into win32 API where everything is possible depending on your awareness.The solution is as simple as creating a main window and creating any number of child windows who uses the main window as parent and all has a hiden window attribute. Then you can create controls on each child window. To switch between the child windows I did this:  `ShowWindow(childWindow1, SW_HIDE);  ShowWindow(childWindow2, SW_SHOW);`. thats it, only that the repaint process after restore does not repaint the child window's controls and its child window.